# Starting with Python - Hamming distance of a list of strings

Tags: python, list, hamming-distance

I'm new in Python and I'm trying to obtain the Hamming distance between a pair of DNA sequences. Although I was able to do this, I don't really know how to obtain a list of Hamming distances of more than one pair of DNA sequences. I wonder if anyone could please guide me on this.

```
dna1 = 'ACCTAT'
dna2 = 'CATTGA'

def distance(strand_a, strand_b):
    if len(strand_a) == len(strand_b):
        i = 0
        n = 0
        while i < len(strand_a):
            if strand_a[i] != strand_b[i]:
                i += 1
                n += 1
            else:
                i += 1
        return(n)
    else:
        raise ValueError("The strings are not the same length")
```

Output:

```
The distance is: 5
```

I wonder if anyone could please help me know which could be the best way to obtain a list of Hamming distances between three pairs of DNA sequences (I tried to do this myself by changing the code above, but I haven't been able to find the solution).

Given these two lists, I want to get the Hamming distance between the 1st, 2nd and 3rd pairs of DNA sequences:

```
dna1 = ['ACTGG','ATGCA','AACTG']
dna2 = ['ACTGA','ATGGG','ATGAC']
```

Where the output would be:

```
distances = [1, 2, 4]
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: To iterate over both lists at the same time, use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip). That should get you started!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np

dna1 = ['ACTGG','ATGCA','AACTG']
dna2 = ['ACTGA','ATGGG','ATGAC']

[(np.array(list(x)) != np.array(list(y))).sum() for x, y in zip(dna1, dna2)]
```

It gives:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: this only works when all strings are of the same length... downvoting.